# Setup rate-limits based on hostname

Tags: haproxy

I'm going through https://www.haproxy.com/blog/four-examples-of-haproxy-rate-limiting/ but unable to grok how to write a configuration which rate-limits based on the `Host` header. Does the following look alright?

```
frontend website
    bind :80
    stick-table  type string  size 100k  expire 30s  store http_req_rate(10s)

    # What do I put here?
    http-request track-sc0 request.header(Host)

    # what does sc_http_req_rate(0) really mean?
    http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 20 }
    default_backend servers
```

Also, what is an easy way to validate whether a rate-limiting configuration works as intended? (not simply test the syntactical validity of the the config)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
  stick-table type string size 100k expire 300s store http_req_rate(60s)
  http-request track-sc0 hdr(Host)
  http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 30 }
```